# Granger causality in bivariate VAR and correlation of shocks

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

If we have a bivariate VAR, like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1t}\\ {x_{2t}}\end{bmatrix}
= C(L)\begin{bmatrix}\epsilon_{1t} \\ \epsilon_{2t}\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} c_{11}(L) & c_{12}(L)\\ c_{21}(L)&c_{22}(L)\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\epsilon_{1t} \\ \epsilon_{2t}\end{bmatrix}
$$
where C(L) is a polynomial in the lag operator, and if we know that $c_{12}(L)$ =0 then $x_{2t}$ does not Granger-cause $y_{1t}$ (note that more formally $c_ij(L) =  c_{ij}^0 + c_{ij}^1L +\dots)$

However, does this mean that the correlation between $\epsilon_{1t}$ and $\epsilon_{2t}$ is zero?

I believe the answer is no. However, where I am getting confused is that if I suppose that they were correlated, then I could use $x_{2t}$ to get information on $\epsilon_{2t}$, and therefore maybe gain some information on $\epsilon_{1t}$. So then $x_{2t}$ would tell me something about $x_{1t}$ (through $\epsilon_{2t}$). **But whether this would imply $x_{2t}$ Granger-causes $x_{1t}$ I do not know.** The reason I think the answer is no is because we are including $\epsilon_{1t}$ in our forecast of $x_{1t}$ already, so whatever information $\epsilon_{2t}$ might give me about $\epsilon_{1t}$ is already incorporated.

Comment: You have both $y$s and $x$s in your text but only $x$s in the formula. Should the $y$s in the text actually be $x$s?

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes. Thank you for pointing that out, and I will fix it now.